# Google bar chart won't show up inside ng-view html partials

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, angularjs-routing

Given the code below which I copy-pasted from [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart?hl=fr), (I've just removed the `html`, `head` and `body` tags). This code performs really well if I simply add it inside my `index.html` page, the bar chart is displayed nicely.

However, if I insert this code as an html partial called by the `ng-view` and `routeProvider` mechanism, the charts are not displayed at all, and the console throws no error.

Do you know what I should check ?

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
            ['2004',  1000,      400],
            ['2005',  1170,      460],
            ['2006',  660,       1120],
            ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
```

I use angularjs 1.2 rc2.

Comment: Maybe you'll be interested in this: http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because inline javascript written in template is not parsed inside `ng-view`. It's a strange behaviour and only solution that I know is even more strange. Include normal jquery script **before** including `angular.js` and... now `<script>` tag gets parsed. Magic.

If someone know a solid explanation of that fact, I'm all ears.

Comment: what do you mean by include normal jquery script ?  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> ?

Comment: Put `<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>` right before `<script src="angular.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: I've downloaded jquery2.03 min, inserted it like you told me, but no success for me...

Comment: I have emptied the cache, and then it goes ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was relieved when you wrote that it works, because I tried to reproduce your success in plnkr and I failed. The fact is that script is now executed, but there is a problem with google chart...

Comment: I have moved to jscharts.js, it worked in an instant. I think I'm gonna use it for now instead of google charts.